# How to change the notification icon in Expo for Android?

Tags: android, react-native, notifications, expo, react-native-push-notification

I'm creating an app with **Expo on SDK 47**, and I've used the "**Expo Notifications**" library to implement notifications that are working perfectly. However, so far I haven't been able to change the notification icon. I've followed the documentation and other information I found while researching, but it hasn't worked.

Some options I've tested in the app.json file are:

Option 1:

```
{
"expo": {
"plugins": [
[
"expo-notifications",
{
"icon": "./assets/notification-icon.png",
"color": "#FFFFFF"
}
]
],
........
}
```

Option 2:

```
{
"expo": {
"notification": {
"icon": "./assets/notification-icon.png"
},
........
}
```

To compile the app, I'm using the "npx expo run:android" command to run it directly on my phone because I'm using other libraries that need native code.

Note: The image for the icon is already in PNG format with a size of 96x96 and in grayscale, as requested in the Expo Notifications documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/

Can anyone help me?

I need to change the notification icon on Android